# Como imprimir texto dentro de uma condição @if{ } em Asp.Net no arquivo cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou com a seguinte situação

```
<td>
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraInicial) às 
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraFinal)
   <br />
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraInicial2) 
   @if (!item.HoraFinal2.Equals(null))
   {
        QUERO IMPRIMIR UM TEXTO SIMPLES AQUI
        echo "às";
   }
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraFinal2)
</td>
```

Quero imprimir a palavra **às** se acontecer a condição **if** sei que em `PHP` é fácil um `echo 'às';` resolve, agora em `ASP.Net MVC` não sei?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podem ser:

Por `razor` `block` `<text>`:

```
<text>às</text> // pode ser varias linhas de texto entre a tag
```

---

ou `@:`, precisa estar dentro do bloco de código `@if(){ // }` `@while(){ // }` etc:

```
@if (true)
{
    @:às //uma linha de texto.
}
```

---

ou `tags` `Html`

```
<span>às</span>
<p>às</p>
```

no seu código:

```
<td>
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraInicial) às 
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraFinal)
   <br />
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraInicial2) 
   @if (!item.HoraFinal2.Equals(null))
   {
        //QUERO IMPRIMIR UM TEXTO SIMPLES AQUI
        <text>às</text>
   }
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraFinal2)
</td>
```

<sup>**Referencias:**</sup>

- [Razor Syntax](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/razor-syntax)
- [Mixing text and functions inside an if/else with MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10210002/6797930)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3: Razor’s `@:` and `<text>` syntax](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)

Comment: MVC3? Tá meio antigo isso aí, não?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez antigo em qual sentido?

Comment: De antigo mesmo. Não está errado, estou só te incomodando :)

Comment: Então, eu achei essa referencia, até procurei antes um mais atual, mas, como não mudou nada e agora é outro tipo, mas, se tiver alguma referencia melhor e puder indicar eu agradeço.